# Can I use a function when naming new columns with quasiquotation?

Tags: r, purrr, tidyeval

I want to make a new column with a name that is a combo of two arguments I gave a function.

Here is some data:

```r
data <- tribble(
  ~one, ~two, ~three,
  'a','b', 'c',
  'd', 'e', 'f'
)
```

If I just want to give it a normal name, this works fine:

```
normal_naming_func <- function(data, name) {
  data %>% 
    mutate({{name}} := str_c(one, two))
}
```

But what if I want the name to be a combination of two different function parameters?

This doesn't work:

```
naming_func <- function(data, name_part1, name_part2) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(str_c({{name_part1}}, {{name_part2}}) := str_c(one, two))
}
```

I get the error:

`Error: The LHS of`:=`must be a string or a symbol`

Neither does this:

```
naming_func <- function(data, name_part1, name_part2) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(str_glue("{{name_part1}}, {{name_part2}}") := str_c(one, two))
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to unquote the LHS. Furthermore, you need to convert the unevaluated names to strings before you can concatenate them:

```r
naming_func <- function(data, name_part1, name_part2) {
  name1 = as.character(ensym(name_part1))
  name2 = as.character(ensym(name_part2))
  data %>% 
    mutate(!! str_c(name1, name2) := str_c({{name_part1}}, {{name_part2}}))
}
```

Remember, `{{…}}` is a shortcut for enquote-then-unquote. However, to construct the new column name you need a slightly different operation: enquote-then-to-string-then-concatenate-then-unquote.

`{{…}}` does not allow you to insert operations in between the quoting and unquoting so the only way to achieve this is to split the operations up and perform them manually, as is done in the code above.

Comment: Wow. I'll remember that: `enquote-then-to-string-then-concatenate-then-unquote`